# Should Tails be upgraded using "sudo apt-get upgrade"?

Tags: tails

When running latest version of Tails (currently 1.1.2) on a USB drive, should you or should you not use "sudo apt-get upgrade" in a terminal to upgrade the components of the Tails instance? If you do run the upgrade, will it [the upgrade] persist after reboot? (I'm thinnking not; I'll have to try it and see.) Also, will configuring persistent volume affect this one way or another? (I'm thinnking not; I'll have to try it and see.) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to upgrade your system by typing sudo apt(-get) upgrade but use the auto update (every 6 weeks) from the Tails Upgrader.

see faq of tails: https://tails.boum.org/support/faq/index.en.html#index10h2

and search for: Should I update Tails using apt-get or Synaptic?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Based on my testing of Tails 1.1.2, it appears that:

1. using `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade` does update the currently running instance of Tails. (in this case, today, `libnss3` and `bash`)
2. The update does not persist on my USB drive after reboot. (I can again update `libnss3` and `bash` again after reboot.)
3. Configuring a persistent volume does not affect persistence of update after reboot.
4. Unless some vulnerability is inadvertently introduced during the update process, I don't see why the current instance of Tails should not be updated.

Please correct me if I misunderstand any of the above.

Answer (score 0):

- I have tried: sudo apt-get update   and
- sudo apt-get upgrade

Both have worked fine and the update/upgrade in     Tails 4.8 is permanent. I have checked it!

But first you have to set a password for the administrator when Tails start.